# How to add a DSQuery script to Excel?

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-excel, dsquery

I have to update AD with home users number, etc. I've written the script and imported the usernames and phone numbers into Excel

Script:

```
dsquery user -samid "username" "OU=Sys,OU=Prod Services,DC=win,DC=ite,DC=com" | dsmod user -mobile  "999" -hometel -u XXXXXX -p XXXXXXXXX
```

In Excel: A1 = Username B1 = Num

How do I get the above script working so it takes the usernames and numbers from Excel and puts them into a batch file?

Comment: Why are you not using PowerShell for this? There are excellent cmdlets ready to do the stuff you're looking for (Get-ADUser and Set-ADuser with CSV import/export)

Comment: Exactly what @pauska said. You should absolutely be using PowerShell for this and not the ds tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, this is definitely in the quick and dirty school of IT Engineering but we've all done it and, actually, Excel is mega handy for this. I do agree with @Pauska that Powershell and CSV's are the way forwards, though.

Anyway, the quickest and easiest way to do this (For a one off job, anyway) is to organise your excel sheet as follows:

```
     Cell A        Cell B       Cell C
  +------------+------------+------------+
1 +  Username  +  Telephone +     Fax    +
  +------------+------------+------------+
2 +   User1    +123456789012+987643210987+
```

And so on. Then, in column D, on Row 2 create a formula that uses concatenation to build your individual command line, ending with something along these lines:

```
="dsquery user -samid '" & A2 & "' 'OU=Sys,OU=Prod Services,DC=win,DC=ite,DC=com' | dsmod user -mobile '" & B2 & "'"
```

You can then select that whole column, copy and paste it notepad and voila - a batch file which will do what you need.

Comment: Tempted to click the down arrow for being this dirty. It's beautiful in it's dirtiness though :)

Comment: I am useless at using excel, where do i enter in the formula-  I highlight the first cell user1 and drag it over to cellC fax, and then down to the end of the file? so where do i enter in my query, I new to this please bear with me.

Comment: @JJJJNR You don't click and drag anything, just put the formula in cell D2 (Based on my diagram). You'll need to tweak the formula more to make it work for you, though. Then, click the little square on the bottom right of D2, and drag down. The formula will autoupdate for each row. Beyond that, you really need to learn how to use Excel for the above to work.

Comment: my excel is broken as it wont autoupdate for each row, despite it been selected in the tools to update, thanks for your help.

Comment: It works! just FYI this is the dsqury I went with in the end: dsquery user -samid username | dsmod user -mobile xxxxxxx do not put any spaces in the numbers when you have them in and also you only need one set of exclamation marks on the side of the excel cell, also do not put the number in comma's –